# NSControl with multiple actions

Tags: cocoa, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a complex custom NSControl that must be able to send more than one message.

For example, on mouse over in must send an action, and on mouse drag in must send another action.

I can't understand how to wire a target to a control and make the control sends whatever message to the target.

In my opinion i have to follow these steps:

1. Instantiate the `NSControl` i.e. `myControl`
2. set the Target action for myControl for every actions (**I don't know how to do that!**)
3. The myControl instance will send action with `[NSApp sendAction: [self action] to: [self target] from: self]`

Can you help me on step 2? and confirm my steps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [Delegation pattern](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Delegation.html). Standard Cocoa controls send at most one action, and use delegation for anything additional. IB does not support setting more than one action, so you can't solve step 2.

If `delegate` is an outlet, you can set it right from IB whenever the delegate is file's owner or also instantiated in this nib, like you would do that for e.g. `NSWindow` or `NSTableView`.

Comment: Do you think that it's better to abandon the NSControl and subclass an UIView ? The unique advantage that I take from the NSControl (I don't use NSCell) is the target-action pattern.

Comment: @MatterGoal Depends on how much of NSControl functionality makes sense for you. Besides IB support for target/action, there are `font`, `enabled`, `objectValue`, `tag` properties etc.

Comment: interesting that uibuttons in iOS have mutlple actions (touch-up-inside touch-down-inside, ...) ... another difference between uikit and appkit